# Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle-core:3.0.0-alpha5

Tags: android, maven

I'm getting this error

> Error:Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle-core:3.0.0-alpha5.
>   Searched in the following locations:
>   file:/C:/Program Files/Android/android-studio-3/gradle/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/gradle-core/3.0.0-alpha5/gradle-core-3.0.0-alpha5.pom
>   file:/C:/Program Files/Android/android-studio-3/gradle/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/gradle-core/3.0.0-alpha5/gradle-core-3.0.0-alpha5.jar
>       https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle-core/3.0.0-alpha5/gradle-core-3.0.0-alpha5.pom
>       https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle-core/3.0.0-alpha5/gradle-core-3.0.0-alpha5.jar
>       Required by:
>       project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-alpha5

My gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 26
buildToolsVersion '25.0.3'
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.the360ls.a360"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 10
    versionName "0.8.1e"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    multiDexEnabled true
    signingConfig signingConfigs.config
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        signingConfig signingConfigs.config
    }
    debug {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.config
    }
}
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-alpha6'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://raw.github.com/Tpaga/tpaga-android-sdk/releases"
        }
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-beta2'
compile 'com.android.support:design:26.0.0-beta2'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
compile 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.0.0-beta2'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.0.0-beta2'
compile 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:26.0.0-beta2'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.0.0-beta2'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.0.2'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.0.2'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.0.2'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.0.2'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'co.tpaga:android:1.0.0'
compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.4.0'
compile 'com.weiwangcn.betterspinner:library-material:1.1.0'
annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.4.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

I dont know how to fix it, Im tryng everything

Comment: just for future reference, you might not want to show your signing information for your app

Comment: Thanks... im so noob

Answer (score 1):

1. change the dependencies

   ```
   dependencies {
       classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
   }
   ```
2. change the `gradle-wrapper.properties`

   ```
   distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.5-all.zip
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Change

1. dependencies in "build.gradle" with existing latest version of the android studio
2. change the "distributionUrl" in gradle-wrapper.properties to latest version

My version is "Android Studio 3.0 Canary 7" and my changes are as follows

1.dependencies {

```
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-alpha7'
```

}

2.
distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.1-milestone-1-all.zip